# Spacing in between toolbar buttons in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 3 buttons in a toolbar. But in the view it should look like a single button , that is there shouldn't be any space in between the 3 toolbar buttons. I cant figure out a way to do this.

Comment: It's a bit unclear, but I'm assuming you want the buttons to be right next to each other? Does it need to be a UIToolbar, or just look like one? I can provide some code to make a UIView that looks like a toolbar if that would help.

Comment: Yss its a translucent toolbar with 4 buttons. 3 buttons are right next to each other. Right now I am having problem with removing the spaces in between the buttons. The buttons are defaultly loaded with a distinct space in between them. I want to remove these spaces in between them, so that the 3 buttons have the visual appearance of a single button, but perform its on actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `UISegmentedControl`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *segmentedButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:segmentedButton, nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexible space between two button.

Thanks,